# Countif function with dynamic rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to use the excel function `Countif` and give it a specific row number for it's range that is defined by the row number of a specific lookup value.

I wrote this formula, but it does not work.

```
=COUNTIF(D(MATCH(A2;A:A;0)):M(MATCH(A2;A:A;0));"<>0")
```

How can I give a row number to my range?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  If a range is dynamic, it would be better to make it a named range, or a table.  You can then refer to that instead.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use OFFSET: something like this

```
=COUNTIF(OFFSET(D1,MATCH(A2,A:A,0),0,1,10),"<>0")
```

Comment: Tried your approach, but this just return the width value specified in the formula. in this case 10, it does not count the number of times a value is 0 in a range.

Comment: Using OFFSET is a good solution, but with this formula it will not work due to the circular reference in the MATCH function. `MATCH(A2,A:A,0)` always returns 2

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the INDIRECT function here, which turns a string into a cell reference.

Also in the MATCH function, you should not let your search-value, 'A2' in this case, be a part of the search range 'A:A'. This creates a circular reference.

Something like this should work:

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("D" & MATCH(B1;A:A;0) & ":M" & MATCH(B1;A:A;0));"<>0")
```